# fullcalendar don't show start_time event

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

i have a fullcalendar set this:

```
allDaySlot: true,
allDayDefault:true,
```

this is capture:

[image: result]

in this case i try to show the event and start time , but dont show on the month, week or day event.
in the day button is show the event and only show on all-day slot, i would like show on the 2 parts timeline and all-day please any suggest.

**update:**

i would like sometime like this:

[image: demo]
in this case show all events, start time in all-day slot and timeline.

thanks.

Comment: Sorry but I was not able to understand what is it that you want. Can you please try explaining a bit more, so that I can help

Comment: i would like show the events on the timeline with start_time and the same to all-day slot..but if i set "allDayDefault" to "true" hidden the events on timeline and hidden the start_time

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do here. If the event is "all-day" and doesn't have any time specified (just date) then it appears in the all-day section. If it does have a time, then it appears on the timeline. It can't appear in both - if it doesn't have a time, where on the timeline would you put it??

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you mean though. If you would like more help can you please 1) show us your code. 2) show us your event data. 2) explain in more detail what you are trying to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for. I have forked a Pen and tried to implement different scenarios which might be serving your needs.

I think you are missing the renderevents in your code:

```
 //An all day event example
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
          title: 'dynamic event',
          start: '2019-05-28',
          allDay: true
        });
  //Not an all day event example
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
          title: 'not an all day event',
          start: '2019-05-28',
          allDay: false
        });
  //An event spanning between two dates
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
          title: 'event with start and end dates',
          start: '2019-05-29',
          end: '2019-05-31'
        });
```

Relevant code can be found here in a [Pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KLxpgQ) which I forked from anon. Let me know if you still have issues.

Comment: if you check when set "allDay:true" the event dont show the start time...

Comment: If you will have a look at their api, https://fullcalendar.io/docs/displayEventTime. it clearly states that the time will be displayed when the allDay attribute is set to false. So, I think that is a limitation on the part of the API. So, do you want me to change the answer mentioning this and then will it be acceptable?